# XPath 1.0, Interpret hex attribute as a number

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I need to compare XML attributes which represent integers, but may be given in decimal or hex (with 0x prefix), using XPath/XSLT-1.0.

Here is a (not working) XSLT to demonstrate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="//node">
        <xsl:if test="@value &gt; 2">
            <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is an XML to input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
    <node value="1"/>
    <node value="3"/>
    <node value="0x03"/>
</body>
```

Here is the desired output. The format is not important; important is only that there is a match on the second and third nodes:

```
3 0x03
```

There is only a match on the second node; the hex node is not interpreted as a number by XML. Can anyone think of a reasonable solution to this problem?

Comment: What's the XSLT processor you are using? This cannot be done in one step in XSLT 1.0. You will have to create an intermediate result (a result tree fragment) with [converted numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905134/convert-hexa-to-integer-in-xslt) and from *that* - with the help of the `node-set()` extension function - you can select nodes the way you want to (`//node[@value &gt; 2]`). Since `node-set()` is not available everywhere, things depend on your XSLT processor version.

Comment: @Tomalak Why do you think it's necessary to have a node-set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The format is not important;

Then for convenience I will demonstrate with an XML format as the output:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/body">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="node">
            <xsl:variable name="decimal">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="starts-with(@value, '0x')">
                        <xsl:call-template name="hex2num">
                            <xsl:with-param name="hex" select="substring-after(@value, '0x')"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:if test="$decimal > 2">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="hex2num">
    <xsl:param name="hex"/>
    <xsl:param name="num" select="0"/>
    <xsl:param name="MSB" select="translate(substring($hex, 1, 1), 'abcdef', 'ABCDEF')"/>
    <xsl:param name="value" select="string-length(substring-before('0123456789ABCDEF', $MSB))"/>
    <xsl:param name="result" select="16 * $num + $value"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($hex) > 1">
            <xsl:call-template name="hex2num">
                <xsl:with-param name="hex" select="substring($hex, 2)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="num" select="$result"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following **test input**:

```
<body>
    <node value="1"/>
    <node value="0x02"/>
    <node value="3"/>
    <node value="0x04"/>
    <node value="0xB1"/>
</body>
```

produces this **result**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
   <node value="3"/>
   <node value="0x04"/>
   <node value="0xB1"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Nice one, Michael. I'm disappointed if there is not an easier way, but with the restriction to 1.0 that's often the case. I take my hat off to you. I've voted up the answer because it is very informative; I'll not be able to test it in context until next week, but presumably it will work and I'll "accept" the answer then. Thank you.

Comment: @Captain With msxsl there is an easier way to do this. Proprietary, but easier. See my answer.

Comment: Interestingly, I accidentally noticed that a colleague dealing with the same XML data set as me, but for a completely different purpose, had to solve the same problem, found this answer using Google, and used it not knowing that I had posted the question!

Answer (score 1):

Since you said that your processor is MSXSL, you can tap into the `msxsl` extensions, which allow you to [define a script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256042(v=vs.110).aspx) that you can use for work that the XSLT processor itself cannot do.

The following uses a small JScript function that converts all hexadecimal numbers that start with `0x` to their decimal counterpart.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:script="http://tempuri.org/script"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl script"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/body">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="node[script:hexToDec(@value) &gt; 2]" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <msxsl:script language="jscript" implements-prefix="script"><![CDATA[
    function hexToDec(nodeList) {
      var firstNode, matches;
      if (nodeList.length) {
        firstNode = nodeList.nextNode();
        matches = /^\s*0x0*([0-9A-F]+)\s*$/i.exec(firstNode.text);
        return matches ? parseInt(matches[1], 16) : firstNode.text;
      }
      return "";
    }
  ]]></msxsl:script>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `msxsl` namespace also allows more advanced ways of extending the XSLT processor, for example with COM DLLs or .NET code, but for this simple scenario JScript does just fine.

Comment: Hi @Tomalak. That's a very useful approach, and a good example for how to use a script with msxsl. I was not aware that this was possible. In my case, this time, for a couple of external reasons I will use the pure XSLT approach. For the general case with multiple attributes that need interpretation/conversion, scripting looks like a significantly more convenient and compact approach.