# Is there a way to convert ipv6 address to a decimal number in xslt1.0

Tags: xslt, type-conversion, hex, xslt-1.0, ipv6

I am trying to check if an ipv6 address falls within a range of 2 ipv6 addresses.
Example: address range :  ff14:0:1::99 - ff14:fe80:1::108
ipv6 address : ff14:fe80:1::99
For that I would need to convert an ipv6 address to decimal.
Is there a way? Can someone suggest.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This could help you start : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905134/convert-a-hexadecimal-number-to-an-integer-in-xslt

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor will you be using?

Answer (score 1):

An IPv6 address is a 128-bit quantity, and the only numeric data type available on XSLT 1.0 is `xs:double`, which doesn't have enough precision to hold this. You could convert to a string representation, but XSLT 1.0 isn't good at comparing strings either (the only way to do it is through xsl:sort, if I remember right). So I would recommend either looking at what your XSLT vendor supports in terms of calling out to other programming languages, or upgrading to XSLT 2.0 or 3.0. Not that that would entirely solve the problem, but it would make a solution a lot easier (for example, you could convert the IPv6 address to a sequence of xs:integers, and then compare the two sequences.)

Comment: Comparing two strings containing an equal number of tokens each (where each token is a decimal number) is not that difficult, even in XSLT 1.0. The real challenge here, IMHO, is expanding the IP to restore the missing all-zero tokens represented by `::`.

Comment: We're talking of comparing order (to see if a value is in a range), not comparing equality. Yes, it can be done using xsl:sort, but it's pretty cumbersome.

Comment: Well, if `A ≤ X` and `X ≤ B`, then X is in the range of A..B. I am not talking about using sort.

Comment: @michael.hor257k i expanded ip and filled ':: 'with missing zeros. For example  ff14:0:1::99 i have this as below
ff14:0:1:0:0:0:0:99 . The same I can remove the : and also if needed i can fill each segment with all 4 like 0000 instead of single 0. But the challenge i face is to compare the string value since for ipv6 we can have alphabets as well and xslt1.0 doesn't have any efficient string operation. I tried converting the ipv6 to decimal using hexadecimal to decimal conversion. But I am getting the output with e+38 in it which again I think is not possible to compare.

Comment: @SwathiS Please edit your question and add your current XSLT.

Comment: @michael.hor257k It's a long time since I've used XPath 1.0 but my memory is that if A and B are strings, A < B converts both strings to numbers.

Comment: I am afraid you are missing my point, which is that you can circumvent the problem of handling 128 bits by comparing each group of 16 bits in turn. Each such group can be converted to decimal and compared individually - as shown in my 1st answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to expand your IPs, then you could use the following example as your starting point for doing the comparisons:

**XML**

```
<input>
    <item>ff14:0:1:0:0:0:0:50</item>
    <item>ff14:0:1:0:0:0:0:99</item>
    <item>ff14:fe80:1:0:0:0:0:99</item>
    <item>ff14:fe80:10:0:0:0:0:108</item>
    <item>ff14:fe80:12:0:0:0:0:108</item>
</input>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="min">ff14:0:1:0:0:0:0:99</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="max">ff14:fe80:10:0:0:0:0:108</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="item">
            <xsl:variable name="compare-to-min">
                <xsl:call-template name="compare">
                    <xsl:with-param name="left" select="."/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="right" select="$min"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="compare-to-max">
                <xsl:call-template name="compare">
                    <xsl:with-param name="left" select="."/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="right" select="$max"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <!-- output -->
            <item value="{.}">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$compare-to-min = -1 or $compare-to-max = 1">out-of-range</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>in-range</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="compare">
    <xsl:param name="left"/>
    <xsl:param name="right"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="':'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="left-token" select="substring-before(concat($left, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
    <xsl:variable name="right-token" select="substring-before(concat($right, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not($left-token)">0</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:variable name="left-dec">
                <xsl:call-template name="hex2num">
                    <xsl:with-param name="hex" select="$left-token" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>    
            <xsl:variable name="right-dec">
                <xsl:call-template name="hex2num">
                    <xsl:with-param name="hex" select="$right-token" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>    
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$left-dec &lt; $right-dec">-1</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$left-dec > $right-dec">1</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <!-- recursive call -->
                    <xsl:call-template name="compare">
                        <xsl:with-param name="left" select="substring-after($left, $delimiter)"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="right" select="substring-after($right, $delimiter)"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="hex2num">
    <xsl:param name="hex"/>
    <xsl:param name="num" select="0"/>
    <xsl:param name="MSB" select="translate(substring($hex, 1, 1), 'abcdef', 'ABCDEF')"/>
    <xsl:param name="value" select="string-length(substring-before('0123456789ABCDEF', $MSB))"/>
    <xsl:param name="result" select="16 * $num + $value"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($hex) > 1">
            <xsl:call-template name="hex2num">
                <xsl:with-param name="hex" select="substring($hex, 2)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="num" select="$result"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <item value="ff14:0:1:0:0:0:0:50">out-of-range</item>
   <item value="ff14:0:1:0:0:0:0:99">in-range</item>
   <item value="ff14:fe80:1:0:0:0:0:99">in-range</item>
   <item value="ff14:fe80:10:0:0:0:0:108">in-range</item>
   <item value="ff14:fe80:12:0:0:0:0:108">out-of-range</item>
</output>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to expand your IPs **and** add leading zeros to each group, then you can use `xsl:sort` as suggested by Michael Kay.

Note that there is no need to convert the values to decimal because hexadecimal values, when padded with leading zeros, will also sort correctly when sorted as text.

**XML**

```
<input>
    <item>ff14:0000:0001:0000:0000:0000:0000:0050</item>
    <item>ff14:0000:0001:0000:0000:0000:0000:0099</item>
    <item>ff14:fe80:0001:0000:0000:0000:0000:0099</item>
    <item>ff14:fe80:0010:0000:0000:0000:0000:0108</item>
    <item>ff14:fe80:0012:0000:0000:0000:0000:0108</item>
</input>
```

**XSLT 1.0 (+EXSLT node-set() function)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="min">ff14:0000:0001:0000:0000:0000:0000:0099</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="max">ff14:fe80:0010:0000:0000:0000:0000:0108</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="item">
            <xsl:variable name="raw">
                <val name="min">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$min"/>
                </val>
                <val name="item">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </val>
                <val name="max">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$max"/>
                </val>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="sorted">
                <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($raw)/val">
                    <xsl:sort/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
            <!-- output -->
            <item value="{.}">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="exsl:node-set($sorted)/val[2]/@name='item'">in-range</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>out-of-range</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <item value="ff14:0000:0001:0000:0000:0000:0000:0050">out-of-range</item>
   <item value="ff14:0000:0001:0000:0000:0000:0000:0099">in-range</item>
   <item value="ff14:fe80:0001:0000:0000:0000:0000:0099">in-range</item>
   <item value="ff14:fe80:0010:0000:0000:0000:0000:0108">in-range</item>
   <item value="ff14:fe80:0012:0000:0000:0000:0000:0108">out-of-range</item>
</output>
```